# % cpu, memory and network usage android application

Tags: ios, performance, android-profiler

Is there any Benchmark to compare cpu, memory and network usage with the one recorded by android profiler when using an application? or is there any best practice: e.g. cpu usage should be kept all the time less than 25%?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's no definitive benchmark. It all depends on your app. If it's a high fidelity game, hitting 100% CPU is not uncommon. But if it's just a simple calculator app, hitting above 10% CPU may be a bit too high. It's also device dependent so 50% on a Pixel 5 doesn't compare to 50% on a Nexus 5.

As an app developer, you should pay more attention to unexpected CPU usage spikes and investigate what's causing them. Similarly for memory usage, you should keep an eye out for memory usage spikes and memory leaks, as opposed to absolute values.

Network usage on the other hand is more about what's expected vs. what's actually being sent over the wires. Take a look at both the bandwidth and number of requests.